# How does Apple password leak check differ from HaveIBeenPwned?

Tags: iphone

I always thought that HaveIBeenPawned was sort of a "gold standard" for lists of known passwords from security breaches, but now it has become apparent that this is not the case ("asking for a friend"):

A password that was (and even sometime later still is) not found on HaveIBeenPwned raised a warning on an iPhone that it had appeared in some data breach.
Of course the immediate action is clear: Change that broken password!!

My question however goes in a different direction: What sources beyond (or completely instead of) the data breaches kindly collected by Troy Hunt does Apple use? I could not find any hints about this in the help on iPhone nor online.

Also, while on one hand, it may seem like an advantage over the competition when Apple have their own extended list of breaches, it would be detrimental to overall security if different providers do not share such lists for a maximized rate of discovery of bad passwords. I am not even sure whether the *general* public would even notice such a difference between providers or would even consider something like "We nag more people into thinking of yet another complex password than any of our competitors" an actual bonus point.

Comment: You mean this? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec78e79fc3b/1/web/1 As you can see, iCloud keychain's "curated list" is different from HIBP's process. So they are different.

Comment: Apple are not going to tell you exactly how their list is curated.

Comment: @schroeder Indeed, that links (first) simply speaks of  "a large set of leaked passwords", which says absolutely nothing. And obviouslyyes, I *have* seen from the different outputs of both oracles for the same password of mine that they *are* different. Fortunately, further down it speaks of "approximately 1.5 billion passwords". On the other hand, HIBP's list makes up some [11-17 GB of zip'ed SHA-1 hashes](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords). Assuming the hashes look essentially random,  that *might* be only about half as long as Apple's list

Comment: HIBP is a list of ***accounts*** with their password hashes. Apple is a ***list of compromised passwords*** which gets updated frequently. These are entirely different processes with different sources. Comparing the two is not helpful nor informative. So, your question is "where does Apple get the content to update their list?" And I'm not sure how that question is relevant.